# Postgres RFC3339 datetime formatting

Tags: json, postgresql, datetime

Is there any way to format datetime to `RFC3339Nano` Eg: `2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00`  in postgres 9.3 or 9.5?

I tried with `to_char`. But there is no documentation how to handle  `T`, `Z`, `+07:00`, `-07:00` etc.

The nearest one I can reach is

```
v2=# select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MSOF');
          to_char
----------------------------
 2016-05-08 12:16:14.493+04
```

Which is default JSON output format datetime in postgres 9.3. Please see below.

```
psql (9.5.1, server 9.3.6)
Type "help" for help.

fetchrdb=> select to_json(current_timestamp);
             to_json
---------------------------------
 "2016-05-08 11:58:04.844548+04"
(1 row)
```

In the case of JSON encoded output from postgres 9.5 is `RFC3339Nano` eg:

```
psql (9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

v2=# select to_json(current_timestamp);
              to_json
------------------------------------
 "2016-05-08T11:59:17.121411+04:00"
```

I could't  find an option to format datetime to RFC3339Nano in postgres 9.3 or 9.5 using `to_char`.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

Is there any hidden option/functions you use to achieve the same? Any help regarding is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I've come to it is this:

```
postgres=# select to_char(('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'::timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"');
           to_char           
-----------------------------
 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
(1 row)
```

This provides the `T` and the microseconds, but not the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

No. PostgreSQL timestamp precision is only up to microseconds.